# Unlist a list of matrix to fill another matrix

Tags: arrays, list, matrix, fill

I have a list of 67 arrays of dimensions 3015 x 3015.
Need to fill another array of 3015 x 3015 with the content of the arrays of the list that is non-zero.

Comment: Maybe you could come up with an example of a list of, say, 5 arrays of dimension 2 x 2 and add them to the question along with your expected output. This way we don't have to guess what you mean when you say an array is non-zero. That is unless I missed something that is special about 67 and 3015.

Comment: What if all 67 arrays are all non-zero. The non-zero contents are not going to fit in one array. How do you want the values ordered in the output array? What language are you using? The answer for MATLAB is going to be much different from the answer for Prolog.

Comment: I´m using RStudio. I clarify some aspects. The arrays in the list have data only on the main diagonal. Those are the data that interest me. With that data I need to fill my target matrix. When I unlist the arrays I have much more data than I need to fill the array, that is, I have many values ​​equal to zero that I don't care about.

Comment: Please add updates and clarifications to the question itself, including updating the tags. Also, if you want someone to know you've responded to them, you need to tag them like @LuceroJoaquin. If you're only interested in the diagonals, why do you need an output array larger than 3015 x 67?